# routing in react-redux application doesn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

Routing doesn't working. Each route always renders component MainPage

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(reducers);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

component App with described routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import MainPage from '../containers/MainPage';
import FavoritesPage from '../containers/FavoritesPage';
import Error404 from '../containers/Error404';

export default () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={MainPage}>
            <Route path="/favorites" component={FavoritesPage}/>
            <Route path="*" component={Error404}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Do you see any problems here?

Answer (score 2):

Your routes are nested which means that child routes will render in the MainPage component. Sometimes this is desired and you only have to render the children somewhere:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <div> { this.props.children }</div>
      )
   }
}
```

If you don't want this move the inner routes outside:

```
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
        <Route path="/favorites" component={FavoritesPage}/>
        <Route path="*" component={Error404}/>
   </Router>
```

Comment: This example is amazing helpful! Thanks a lot!